# Prolog - proof tree misses possibilities

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I have the following `Prolog` Program:

```
p(f(X), Y) :- p(g(X), g(Y)).
p(g(X), Y) :- p(f(Y), f(X)).
p(f(a), g(b)).
```

The prolog proof tree has to be drawn for the predicate `p(X, Y)`.

[image: Prolog - proof tree]

**Question**:

- Why is `Y` matched to `Y1/Y` and not to `Y/Y1` and why is `Y` used further on?
- if I match a predicate (e.g. `p(X, Y)`), I get a new predicate (e.g. `p(g(X1), g(Y))`) - why contains `p(g(X1), g(Y))` just one subtree? I mean, shouldn't it have 3 because the knowledgebase contains 3 statements - instead of just 1?
- And why is at each layer of the tree matched with something like X2/X1 and so on ? and not with the predicate before ? 
  Shouldn't it be `g(X1)/fX5, g(Y1)/Y5` ?

**Note**: Maybe it seems that I have never done a tutorial or something. But I did.. I appreciate every help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good questions!

> Why is `Y` matched to `Y1/Y` and not to `Y/Y1` and why is `Y` used further on?

The naming here seems a little arbitrary in that they *could* have used `Y/Y1` but then would need to use `Y1` further on. In this case, they chose `Y1/Y` and use `Y` further on. Although the author of this expression tree was inconsistent in their convention, I wouldn't be too concerned about the naming as much as whether they follow the variable correctly down the tree.

> if I match a predicate (e.g. `p(X, Y)`), I get a new predicate (e.g. `p(g(X1), g(Y))`) - why contains `p(g(X1), g(Y))` just one subtree? I mean, should'nt it have 3 because the knowledgebase contains 3 statements - instead of just 1?

First a word on *term* versus *predicate*. A term is only a predicate in the context of `Head :- Body` in which case `Head` is a term that forms the head of a predicate clause. If a term is an argument to a predicate (for example, `p(g(X1), g(Y))`, the `g(X1)` and `g(Y)` are *not* predicates. They are just terms.

More specifically in this case, the term `p(g(X1), g(Y))` only has one subtree because it *only matches the head of **one** of the 3 predicate clauses* which is the one with the head `p(g(X), Y)` (it matches with `X = X1` and `Y = g(Y)`). The other two can't match since they're of the form `p(f(...), ...)` and the `f(...)` term cannot match the `g(X1)` term.

> And why is at each layer of the tree matched with something like `X2/X1` and so on ? and not with the predicate before ? 
>   Shouldn't it be `g(X1)/fX5, g(Y1)/Y5` ?

I'm not sure I'm following this question, but the principle to follow is that the tree is attempting to use the *same* variable name if it applies to the *same* variable in memory, whereas a different variable name (*e.g.*, `X1` versus `X`) is used if it's a *different* `X`. For example, if I have `foo(X, Y) :- <some code>, bar(f(X), Y).` and I have `bar(X, Y) :- blah(X), ...` then the `X` referred to in the `bar` predicate is different than the `X` referred to in the `foo` predicate. So we might say, in the call to `foo(X, Y)` we're calling `bar(f(X), Y)`, or alternatively, `bar(X1, Y)` where `X1 = f(X)`.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I have rarely seen a **worse** method to explain Prolog than what you show here.

**Yes**, I expect the author meant `Y/Y1` instead of `Y1/Y` in both cases, otherwise the notation would be quite inconsistent.

As to your other questions: You are facing the usual problems that arise when taking such an extremely *operational* view of Prolog. The core issue is that this method **doesn't scale**: You do not have the mental capacity to carry this approach through. Don't take this personal: Humans in general are bad at keeping all details of an execution tree that grows exponentially in mind. This makes the whole approach extremely cumbersome and error-prone. For comparison, consider why human grandmasters have stopped competing against chess computers already many years ago. In this concrete case, note for example that the rightmost branch does not even arise in actual Prolog execution, but the graph wrongly suggests that it does!

Part of the problem here is a confusion in **terminology**: Please note that Prolog uses **unification** (not "matching", which is one-sided unification). When you **unify** a goal with a clause **head** and the unification **succeeds**, then you get **bindings** for variables. You continue *with these bindings in place*.

To make the whole approach remotely feasible, consider **fragments** of your program.

For example, suppose I *only* give you the following *fact*:

```
p(f(a), g(b)).
```

And you then query:

```
?- p(X, Y).
X = f(a),
Y = g(b).
```

This answers shows the **bindings** for `X` and `Y`. First make sure you understand this, and understand the difference between these bindings and a "new predicate" (which does not arise!).

Also, there are no "statements", but 3 **clauses**, which are logical **alternatives**.

Now, again to simplify the whole task, consider the following **fragment** of your program, in which I *only* look at the two *rules*:

```
p(f(X), Y) :- p(g(X), g(Y)).
p(g(X), Y) :- p(f(Y), f(X)).
```

Already with this program, we get:

```
?- p(X, Y).
nontermination
```

Adding a further pure clause *cannot prevent* this nontermination. Thus, I recommend you start with this reduced version of your program, and consider it in more depth.

From there, you can add the remaining fact again, and consider the differences.